# Application not closing "gracefully" when users logs off (Windows)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have a RDS farm (Win 2008 R2) and the users need to use a third party application (Unify OpenScape Contact Center) for call center purposes. It logs on the specific user to specific phones. When the users closes the application manually, basically closing the window, the app "does what it have to do" and automatically logs off the user from the phone.

The problem happens when the user leaves the app running and logs off from their sessions (basically Start->logoff), it's like Windows terminates (kill) the process, and the users keeps logged to the phone, then the next day some manager has to force a logoff and so on, generating problems.

Is it a default behavior on Windows logoff? Is there a way to configure it to maybe "gracefully" close the applications (send WM_CLOSE)?

I could make a script to generate a custom "logoff" shortcut to users and disable the logoff buttom, then try to gracefully close the app before logoff, but still sounds like a weird workaround to me. Also, doesn't solve the problem for inactive/disconnected sessions being ended by Windows after timeout.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the program. Have you contacted Unify to fix it?

Comment: Agreed, that is the one and only answer. Buggy apps are buggy.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application bug, not a problem with Windows. Call the software vendor and kindly let them know that they need to handle the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message and/or the CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT control signal and/or the various [WTS-related window messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828(v=vs.85).aspx) in their application's message loop that they need to handle.

Additionally, they could design the server more intelligently and automatically log off accounts that haven't sent some sort of "heartbeat" in some time.

Applications that do not handle this message, and don't implement these *basic* design considerations could be considered "incomplete" and "not compatible with Windows" and essentially we should not tolerate this type of garbage software on the market.

Sorry, I have strong feelings on the subject.